# Most obvious meaning of the phrase "Hit me baby one more time"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

Long, long time ago there was a song of Britney Spears "Baby one more time" with phrase **"Hit me baby one more time"**.
Since that time I wondering, what is primary meaning of 'hit me' in this context? I understand that 'hit me' may have many different meanings: *'push me'*, *'reach me'*, *'impress me'*, may be even *'f*ck me'*.
But what is the most obvious meaning of this phrase for native English-speaking peoples?
When you're hearing this song, what you think Britney exactly asking her ex-boyfriend to do with her, when she singing **"hit me baby one more time"**?
Thanks in advance for your answers!

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/...Baby_One_More_Time_(song)

Comment: Ivan, I think this question strays into seeking personal opinion with "When you're hearing this song, what you think Britney [is] exactly asking?" Questions that encourage primarily opinion-based answers are off-topic on this site. For further guidance, see [ask], and take the site **[Tour]** :-)

Comment: If you're unhappy with the Wikipedia explanation and *you want a more serious analysis* rather than just an opinion poll, consider reframing your question on our other site [Literature.SE], whose Meta discussion confirms that [analysis of song lyrics is on-topic](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67/are-songs-and-poems-on-topic) and even that [it's ok to ask about a Britney Spears song](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/858/what-are-the-rules-for-asking-about-song-lyrics).

Comment: Maybe I should clarify my question. For example, if my ex-girlfriend ask me to hit her one more time, what does it mean? I understand that 'hit me' may have many different meaning in different phrases but what is primary one in context of asking by the girl from a man? What should I do to comply with her request? It's not about Britney and her song, it's about general meaning of this phrase.

Comment: If your ex-girlfriend asks you to hit her, and you do not know what she means, then you should ask **her** what she means, not us.

Comment: Sorry, it's hard to explain... I'm asking about PRIMARY meaning of this phrase. Not about my ex-girlfriend or Britney. For example, word 'glasses' may mean 'eyeglasses' or may mean 'glass caps for drinking', but if some old man ask me 'Give me my glasses', I'll give him his eyeglasses, not his glass caps, because in this context PRIMARY meaning of this word in 90% is eyeglasses, not glass caps. And there is no reason for me to ask him what does he means. And I presume that phrase 'hit me one more time' in this context has its PRIMARY meaning too. So I ask you, what is this meaning. No more.

Comment: @Ivan: What do  you mean "glass caps"? Perhaps caps -> cups?

Comment: Yes, glass cups.

Comment: It's very sad that you set this question on hold. Especially when there is at least one good answer (by Hot Licks). And answer of Hot Licks is not opinion-based (there are many evidence in Net, that 'hit me' is really used in blackjack in a very similar way) :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "literal" interpretation of "hit me" would be for someone playing a card game like blackjack to be telling the dealer to deal another card.

But the term has escaped Las Vegas, and now carries the general meaning of "do it again".  Without considerable context it's impossible to say with any preciseness what "it" is.

In the context of the song it could mean simply "kiss me", or it could mean contact that is rather more physical.  The song is intentionally vague in this regard.

Comment: Hot Licks, thank you! I didn't know about this Las Vegas meaning before. So whole phrase "hit me baby one more time" may mean just "do it baby with me (or to me) one more time"?

Comment: Uhm, the *literal* meaning of "hit me" is "strike me" (physically).  The "give me another card" (or drink, when said to a bartender) meaning is *figurative*.

Comment: @michael.hor257k - That's why I put "literal" in quotes.